# Forcing a typecast of a custom object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have 2 constructors and a member function defined

```
function A() {}
function B() {}
A.prototype.a = function(){}
```

And I've instantiated a `B`. How can I force a conversion to make it an `A`?

```
o = new B();
//What should I put here?
o.a();
```

I'm new to js. And I have a feeling that whether `o` mentioned above is an `A` or a `B` is merely controlled by a reference to a `prototype`. Therefore, I feel typecast should be possible.

Answers, as well as explanations that can help me understand js objects, are welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change (that is, completely swap-out) the prototype of an object once it's been created (yet; in a future version of JavaScript, it's likely to be possible).

Objects in JavaScript are enormously malleable, though. You can do this, for instance:

```
o.a = A.prototype.a;
```

...and then `o` will have the `a` function. If you wanted to give it all of the enumerable properties of `A.prototype` (including any from *its* prototype):

```
var name;
for (name in A.prototype) {
    o[name] = A.prototype[name];
}
```

The `prototype` property of functions is a completely normal, boring object assigned to a normal, boring property on the function. When you use `new` to create an object using that function (which is called a "constructor function"), the function's `prototype` property is assigned to the newly-created object as its underlying prototype (which has no name you can access in code [yet]).

As of ES5 (reasonably supported in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and IE9; not in IE8 and earlier), you can *get* the prototype of an object via [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.2), and you can create objects assigning them a prototype without going through constructor functions by using [`Object.create`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5), but you can't change what an object's prototype is once it's been created.

Some JavaScript engines (like the one in Firefox) have a currently-non-standard extension called `__proto__` which lets you directly access and manipulate the prototype of an object, by treating it as a property. E.g.:

```
o.__proto__ = A.prototype;
```

...but that is not standard at present. It may well be part of the next standard, though. If you're interested in information about the upcoming ES6, you can find draft specifications and such [here](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aspecification_drafts).

Comment: Why is `__proto__` not mentioned?

Comment: Note that `setPrototypeOf` is already in the drafts and confirmed: https://bugs.ecmascript.org/show_bug.cgi?id=264

Comment: @JanDvorak: I was just adding `__proto__`.

Comment: @JanDvorak: I don't see `setPrototypeOf` in the [harmony list](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?do=index&id=harmony%3Aharmony), but I do suspect it will be in it, yes.

Comment: Also note that `__proto__` is a part of the future specification as well (or was it removed again?)

Comment: Chrome does support `__proto__` (in the console, at least)

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yes, recent versions of Chrome and opera both support `__proto__`.

Comment: Hmm... IE9 does _not_ support `__proto__`.

Comment: `__proto__` is still good enough for writing plugins and bookmarklets for geeks, though ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak: You're right, `__proto__` the phoenix has risen again, it's in the current (as of this writing) draft spec, Section B.3.1.

Comment: Too bad IE _including IE9_ is the outsider here.

Comment: @JanDvorak: I think we can cut them slack, A) because they did *so much* in IE9 to bring it forward, and B) because there's been a lot of back-and-forth on `__proto__`. Many (including me) feel that it's not at *all* smart to have a property-like-thing with a weird name for this, `setPrototypeOf` would have been entirely sufficient. But apparently we're losing this battle.

Comment: I do think `setPrototypeOf` would have been sufficient, and I do like `__proto__`. What side this makes me on?

Comment: Very informative answer. Also, the discussion between you and @JanDvorak are quite interesting. Thank you.